# Array comparison for integer

Tags: c++, c

Here I am comparing two array element , If array element are equal `SETPASSWORD=1;` else `SETPASSWORD=0;`
But Here It is always printing password set status 1 even array are not equal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARY_SIZE 4
int password_set;
int main (void)
{
  //Local Declarations
  int numbersA[ARY_SIZE];
  int numbersB[ARY_SIZE];
  int i;
  int j;

  //Statements
  printf("Please Enter 10 Integers For Array A\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < ARY_SIZE; i++)
    scanf("%d", &numbersA[i]);

  printf("\nPlease Enter 10 Integers For Array B\n");
  for (int j = 0; j < ARY_SIZE; j++)
    scanf("%d", &numbersB[j]);

  for (int i = 0; i < ARY_SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < ARY_SIZE; j++)
    {
      if (numbersA[i] == numbersB[j])
        password_set=1;
      else
        password_set=0;
    }
  }
  printf(" password setstaus =%d",password_set);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us the array elements you have tried.

Comment: numbersA=1 2 3 4 number B= 1 0 0 0

Comment: You set `password_set` every loop iteration so the result is going to be telling you whether the 10th numbers equal or not.

Comment: Using C++: `password_set = std::equal(numbersA, numbersA + ARY_SIZE, numbersB);`

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is wrong. You must exit the loop as soon as one pair of numbers is non equal.

And you also need only one loop :

```
password_set = 1 ;

for (int j = 0; j < ARY_SIZE; j++)
{
  if (numbersA[j] != numbersB[j])
  {
    password_set = 0;
    break ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Then where to set password_set = 1; if i set globally as 1 it will be always 1. if array are equalto 1 then only set to 1 else set to zero

Comment: You set `password_set = 1` just before the loop as shown in the answer. If the two arrays are different `password_set` will be set to 0, otherwise it will stay 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your compare each value of the array in your for (if (numbersA[i] == numbersB[j])

It resets the value of password_set at each iterations. It means that the result printed will be the last index of your array.

And btw you need only one loop

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you comparison is wrong. Because you want to test two arrays is equal or not, you just test each number of these two arrays.

like this:

```
    password_set = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARY_SIZE; i++) {
        if (numbersA[i] != numbersB[i]) {
            password_set=0;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The password_set flag should really not be set back to 1 if just one pair happens to be equal (that would overwrite an unequality found before). You either initialize it to 1 and exit when the first inequality is found, or for god's sake continue to the end of the loop, but don't overwrite the 0 later with a 1 in the loop.

Comment: Perhaps apple has a job offer for you if you are interested in safety critical software ;-) (scnr)